# Display line number in head and tail command like `cat -n`

Tags: linux, cat, tail, head

**`cat` without `-n`**

```
user@linux:~$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf | head -4
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
user@linux:~$
```

There is `-n` option in `cat` command to display the line number of the file.

```
user@linux:~$ cat -n /etc/sysctl.conf | head -4
     1  #
     2  # /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
     3  # See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
     4  # See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ cat -n /etc/sysctl.conf | tail -4
    74  # Debian kernels have both set to 1 (restricted) 
    75  # See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt
    76  #fs.protected_hardlinks=0
    77  #fs.protected_symlinks=0
user@linux:~$
```

What about `head` and `tail` command? Is there any option to view the line number in `head` and `tail` without using `cat -n` and pipe the output to `head` or `tail`?

I've tried `head -n <filename>` and `tail -n <filename>` but no line number displayed on the output.

```
user@linux:~$ head -n4 /etc/sysctl.conf
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ tail -n4 /etc/sysctl.conf
# Debian kernels have both set to 1 (restricted) 
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt
#fs.protected_hardlinks=0
#fs.protected_symlinks=0
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: `-n` is the option for selecting the number of lines that you'd want `head` or `tail` to return.

Comment: "Do one thing and do it right". Sometimes a tool (e.g. `cat -n`) duplicates a feature of another tool (here `nl -d '' -b a`, note it's portable and `cat -n` is not), but in general you should pipe tools one to another instead of expecting a single tool to do everything. This is in the core of the Unix philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

> What about head and tail command? Is there any option to view the line number in head and tail without using `cat -n` and pipe the output to head or tail?

No; the current versions of [head](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) and [tail](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html) do not have any way to add line numbers to the output *themselves*.

Comment: There's nothing stopping the user from using `head file | cat -n` though.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid I was being too brief; I was responding directly to the "can head or tail number lines directly?"

Answer (score 1):

How about to use `less` command?

`less -N +F /etc/sysctl.conf`